# How can I concatenate a JavaScript string and a JavaScript variable and put it in an h1 in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a digital journal application and for my heading, I want a user to be able to submit an input of their name and have it show up in the heading.

Before they submit their name, the heading would read "Welcome to Digital Journal."

After they submit their name, the heading would read "Welcome to Digital Journal, ______."

This is what I already tried for my JavaScript.

```js
let nameVar = "Welcome to Digital Journal, " + document.getElementById("myNameIs").value;


<!-- not working -->
function submitName() {
  document.getElementById("beginWelcome").innerHTML = nameVar;
}
```

This is my HTML.

```
<div class="fadeInText">
  <h2 id="beginWelcome">Welcome to Digital Journal,</h2>
</div>

<div>
    <p id="nameQ">What's your name?</p>

  <div id="nameDiv">
    <input type="username" id="myNameIs">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="submitButtonDiv">
    <input onclick="submitName()"id="submitButton" type="submit">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code gets the value of the input before the user has a chance to type anything and click the button. That should happen inside that "submit" function.

Comment: put the `let nameVar = "Welcome to Digital Journal, " + document.getElementById("myNameIs").value; ` inside the function so it can be changed when submitted

Answer (score 1):

As the comment above already stated, you are trying to set the name variable before the user has typed anything and should instead execute the logic inside the `submitName()` function:

```js
function submitName() {
  const inputEl = document.getElementById("myNameIs");
  const titleEl = document.getElementById("beginWelcome");
  titleEl.innerHTML = `Welcome to Digital Journal, ${inputEl.value}`;
}
```

In the above example I first get the title and input elements and then set the `innerHTML` of the title element to a template literal containing the title concatenated with the value of the input.